# JBoss Drools and Mule integration

Tags: drools, esb, mule

Has anyone had any experience integrating [JBoss Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools) with [Mule ESB](http://www.mulesoft.org/)?

While [Apache ServiceMix](http://servicemix.apache.org/home.html) appears to have good Drools support (http://servicemix.apache.org/servicemix-drools.html), the web based monitoring and tooling in Mule make it particularly useful for us as we often have non-technical service workers needing access to information around messaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the Mule committers has recently been working to update the Drools support in Mule. You can ask this question on the Mule user mailing list and probably get an up to date answer and a pointer to the work in progress code.